# Fetching json using ajax to display to user

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

This is my PHP code fetching as json which works fine and displaying the json data as i have checked it. but not displaying when i want the same to be displayed to user.

```
<?php>
    include('connect.php');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT filmName, url, filmYear FROM table");

    $outp = "[";
    while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
        $outp .= '{"Film":"'  . $rs["filmName"] . '",';
        $outp .= '"Path":"'   . $rs["url"]        . '",';
        $outp .= '"Year":"'. $rs["filmYear"]     . '"}'; 
    }
    $outp .="]";

    $conn->close();

    echo($outp);
    ?>
```

Here i am passing url to fetch data to user as getfilms.php which is having above code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav id="nav01"></nav>

<div id="main">
  <h1>films</h1>
  <div id="id01"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "getfilms.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        var arr = obj.records;
        var i;
        var out = "<table><tr><th>Film</th><th>Path</th><th>Year</th></tr>";

        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].Film +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Path +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].Year +
        "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>"
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you do not build the json yourself, but rather use json_encode for that purpose.  $outp[] = $row; echo json_encode($outp);

Comment: @ twice ejr as i am newbe how i can implement to above code? and also this will work on mobile app?

Comment: Yes, I have pasted it here for you: http://pastebin.com/TNAt65zU
I think the javascript should work on mobile apps as well. Are you building a native or a web-app?

Comment: @ twice ejr that is working fine but how i will fetch the same to user as i have the above html file? because currently its coming as json file only

Comment: Comment out the line: "var arr = obj.records".
Replace 'var obj =' for 'var arr ='    --   you had targeted an undefined index on obj variable (records does not exist in the json array on obj)

Comment: twicejr Thanks again i have posted the answer on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your build json which is not a good way to do this.

make a array of and then simple **echo json_encode(Your_array);**

this give you a perfect json format.

to parse json value please use this..

**var result = $.parseJSON(response);**

use this **result.value;**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @twicejr it worked fine. i am posting the answer on behalf of you.

Comment out the line: "var arr = obj.records". Replace 'var obj =' for 'var arr =' -- you had targeted an undefined index on obj variable (records does not exist in the json array on obj)

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        //var arr = obj.records;
```